# Не запускается сервис через AlarmManager

Tags: android-service, broadcast-receiver, android-alarm-manager, android-broadcastreceiver

Задача: запускать ежедневно в конце дня сервис, который собирает статистику и записывает ее в БД.
Реализую, используя AlarmManager. 
Код активити:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
public DBHelper dbHelper;
private Context context;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Intent alarm = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AlarmBroadcastReceiver.class);
    boolean alarmRunning = (PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 0, alarm, PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE) != null);
    Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, cal.get(Calendar.YEAR));
    calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, cal.get(Calendar.MONTH));
    calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 23);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 59);
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

    if(!alarmRunning) {
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 0, alarm, 0);
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);

    }

}
```

Код ресивера:

```
public class AlarmBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

final String LOG_TAG = "myLogs";

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "TIME!");
    context.startService(new Intent(context, MyService.class));
}
```

Код сервиса:

```
public class MyService extends Service {
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    DBHelper dbHelper = new DBHelper(getApplicationContext());
    DBHelper.update_db(getApplicationContext(),dbHelper);
    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}

@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}
```

Проблема в общем-то в том, что сервис не запускается. Логи в AlarmBroadcastReceiver тоже не срабатывают.

**update:** в манифесте ресивер прописал

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разобрался. Нужно использовать флаг RTC.

**UPDATE:**
Флаги, название которых начинается с RTC, ориентируются на системное время. И время запуска таких будильников надо указывать относительно System.currentTimeMillis. Т.е. это RTC и RTC_WAKEUP.

Флаги, которые начинются с ELAPSED_REALTIME, ориентируются на время от начала включения устройства. Время запуска таких будильников надо указывать относительно SystemClock.elapsedRealtime(). Т.е. это ELAPSED_REALTIME и ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP.

Ошибочным было указывание "относительного" флага ELAPSED_REALTIME, ведь время я задавал "абсолютное".

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы.